# How can I localise my application with pygettext in multiple folders?

Tags: python-2.7, gettext

I want to localise my application using pygettext (currently the translations are hard-coded and it's difficult to modify them). I have tried it and I managed to generate a .po and a .mo file for a single file. Following a tutorial I found on internet, I put this code on one of the files:

```
def init_localization():
# Searches config file, if created.
config_name = 'default'
configpath = find_config(config_name)
try:
    config_module = Config(configpath)
    if config_module.core.not_configured:
        lang = raw_input("Language code: ")
    else:
        if config_module.has_option('core', 'lang'):
            lang = config_module.lang
        else:
            lang = raw_input("Language code: ")
except ConfigurationError:
    lang = raw_input("Language code: ")

filename = ("translations/messages_%s.mo" % lang)

try:
    logging.debug("Opening message file %s for locale %s", filename, lang)
    trans = gettext.GNUTranslations(open( filename, "rb" ) )
except IOError:
    logging.debug( "Locale not found. Using default messages" )
    trans = gettext.NullTranslations()

trans.install()
```

Then, I do `_("Text to translate")` in every string. I generate the .po file, translate it and then generate the .mo file. I run the code and it works fine.

The problem is that my application is very modular (around 45 modules) and I think that making this for every module would be a bit confusing. Searching in stackoverflow, I found an answer that says that putting `gettext.install()` at the `__init__.py` file it's enough, but it didn't work for me. This is my `__init__.py` file:

```
import gettext
gettext.install('helloworld', 'translations/')
```

I have removed the install() of the main module and when I run the module I get the error `NameError: global name '_' is not defined`.

How can I make a single .mo file for all modules? Note that they are in different folders:

```
main folder/
    __init__.py
    main_module.py
    some modules/
        __init__.py
        module.py
        more modules/
            __init__.py
            module.py
```

I'm using Python 2.7.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I need to provide mor information.